# In VB.NET, is it possible to break on an AutoProperty's Set?

Tags: vb.net, properties, visual-studio-2019

In VB.NET, if a property is defined thusly:

```
Private _status As String
Public Property Status() As String
    Get
        Return _status
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _status = value
    End Set
End Property
```

... then it is trivial to add a break to the Set part of the property in Visual Studio.

However, if it is defined as an AutoProperty:

```
Public Property Status() As String
```

, can a break still be added to the Set somehow, without converting it temporarily to a property with a backing variable as in the first example?

Comment: You need an instruction to break on. There is a full property with set assignment instruction behind the vb.net scenes, but you don't see it. The auto property in VB.NET is basically a placeholder for the full property and no you can't stop on the placeholder.

Comment: You might be able to find the setter and a spot to break if you look at the disassembly at runtime.  In the alternative, you could expand it into the manual equivalent of an auto property for debugging purposes (which would admittedly be a bit of a PITA especially if you need to do it for more than one).